# Watir Button Element not enabled after form requirements are filled

Tags: html, ruby, heroku, phantomjs, watir

I am trying to use watir in ruby to automatically complete a form for me. However, when the form is completed the button element "Continue" is not enabled. It works when I run the test in chrome but when i use phantomJS it does not work.

For example, in phantomJS the form thinks that I didnt complete the form even when i did. it shows as below (doesnt work).

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h0TJi.png)

when i run my script but i open my browser with chrome instead of phantomJS i get the following (works):

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2hsqQ.png)

Has anyone else experienced this?
Any idea how to fix this?

I've tried: 
- sleeping for a longer time
- Tabing to other text fields
- Completing the Middle name field

Nothing seems to enable the button "Continue"

Comment: Have you tried doing some old fashioned debugging? Maybe output your validation functions to the console and record those in your phantomJS test? This also could be related to Angular, so you may want to expand the tags to include that.

Comment: I have not tried that. How do I output validation function to the console?

Comment: PhantomJS is pretty much deprecated. Chromedriver is faster, and headless mode is almost feature complete if you absolutely need headless.

Comment: I installed the chrome driver to heroku and uploaded my script to open chrome instead of phantomjs however it is still not enabling the "continue" button

Comment: it is entirely possible that chrome's js engine is faster than phantomJS..  If the system does some kind of evaluation after every field is filled, it may be in the middle of that when you try to populate the last name field. 
 Might be you need to introduce a very small delay before trying to fill in the last name, which as indicated in Andrey's answer appears to be empty on the screenshot you sent.

Answer (score 0):

On the first image that you posted Last Name is not filled in.
Assuming that the screenshot is wrong and the button is still disabled after all required fileds are filled in, you should figure out what triggers the enabling of the button and trigger that manually.

After that you should be able to to click the button.

Comment: the button changes to "continue" when all the field with * are filled. I just posted that screenshot as an example. When i run the script in PhantomJS it shows that every field was filled but the button still didnt change. My script crashes saying that the element button "continue" was not found.